# QuerySelector set text value

Tags: javascript

I have this loop which should set the `<input type="text"/>` value to none and update the placeholder.
When I log the node it works fine but the `value` and `placeholder` are not updated? What is wrong?

data is a JSON object.

```
var data = {"password":"password","username":"xhinii"};
```

**JS :**

```
var data = {"password":"password","username":"xhinii"};

for(var prop in data) {
    console.log(document.querySelector('input[name = "' + prop + '"]')); //works fine. logs the node.
    document.querySelector('input[name = "' + prop + '"]').value = ''; //doesn't work
    document.querySelector('input[name = "' + prop + '"]').setAttribute('placeholder', data[prop]);//doesn't work
}
```

Comment: Your data is **NOT** a JSON object. Please do not edit your question to fix a typo or issue which is causing the problem that you were posting about. Instead, if the problem was caused by a simple mistake or a typo, close the question. If you have remaining/different questions, open a new question.

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is a string-based representation used for exchanging information. What you have here is a plain old everyday JavaScript object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You shouldn't parse an object just use it :

```js
var data= {"password":"password","username":"xhinii"};

for(var prop in data) {
    document.querySelector('input[name = "' + prop + '"]').value = prop; 
    document.querySelector('input[name = "' + prop + '"]').setAttribute('placeholder', data[prop])
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name='password' />
<input name='username' />
```

Comment: And whats the solution?

Comment: What you mean? why would you want to update the DOM in browser?

Comment: `text value` should be updated because your code is correct, you should check the data you have in `data`.

Comment: `var data = JSON.parse({"password":"password","username":"xhinii"});`

Comment: You shouldn't parse this object since its javascript object just use it directly ,check my update.

Comment: Hey I'm sorry my code was fine and the problem was not how I parsed the object. I had two inputs with the same name and the first was updating not the one I wanted. I fixed it

Comment: yeah I know It is not that way in my code. I just wanted to show you that I was parsing it. In reality Im using JSON.parse after I get the response from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

For my case to upadte the input text directly , It is easier, as your reference:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element_id');
element.value = 'random_value';
```

FYR:https://teamtreehouse.com/community/change-a-value-of-an-input