# How to set input value by JavaScript document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Just I want to add input value using javascript.
Here's [priject link](http://test2.my247entertainment.com/test1.html)!> add to cart > Proceed to Checkout || then you get the checkout page.

Actually I want to add automatically Zipcode value in the checkout page.
I try this methood but dosen’t work

```
document.querySelector('#shipping-new-address-form div:nth-child(8) input').value = '12345';
```

Can anyone help to solve this issue?

Comment: there is a nested div inside a `div:nth-child(8)`, so you have to select this: `'#shipping-new-address-form div:nth-child(8) div input'`;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QuerySelector set text value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672566/queryselector-set-text-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome console to ensure about your query finding target element and setting its value, exactly because your selector may not be right.

It should be like that

```
document.querySelector('input[name = "' + prop + '"]').setAttribute('placeholder', data[prop])
```

There is another answer like this here [QuerySelector set text value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672566/queryselector-set-text-value)

Comment: This method works consol, not working on page you can see project checkout page. Can you help in this issue. ```document.querySelector('#shipping-new-address-form div:nth-child(8) input').value = '12345';

Comment: @Tilik Paul have you tryed to call other said about onpageload or jquery onpageready If that is not worked only the way you can do that with document.getElementById. please try end share me result to working out

Answer (score 0):

on the checkout page, you can define `onload` event.

```
<body onload="fillZipCode()">
<script>
function fillZipCode() {
  document.querySelector('#shipping-new-address-form div:nth-child(8) input').value = '12345';
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for help, this function working console log but on the page not working, I already add my project page. You can see that what is the console error. Can you help, please?

Comment: To fix that you have to add an id to the element Zip/Postal Code textbox.. you need to use something like this:  document.getElementById("someID").value = '12345'   Where someID is the ID of that text box..

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add input field and its value using JavaScript then you can use below script.

```
<script>

function myFunction() 
{
  var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
  input.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input.setAttribute("value", "1234");
  document.body.appendChild(input);
}

myFunction();
</script>
```